# Как поменять фон главного меню в игре Robox

Tags: roblox

Хочу создать свою программу для создания модификаций к игре Roblox(API) и решил, что мне стоит начать с изменения фона главного меню. Как мне это сделать?(без использования посторонних API, только если с помощью проводника)

Comment: C API будет проще. Программы не рассчитаны на то, чтобы в них влезать грубо, через файловую систему и блокнот.